# MongoDB C# Driver Unique Index PartialFilterExpression for when isArchived is false

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a collection of items that can be deleted. I would like to have a unique index on the name so long as `isArchived` is `false`. I can do it with the mongo command line, but I can't seem to find much documentation for the C# driver. Currently we have the index:

```
        await JobsCollection.Indexes.CreateOneAsync("{Name: 1}", new CreateIndexOptions
        {
            Unique = true
        });
```

I assume that would become something close to:

```
        await JobsCollection.Indexes.CreateOneAsync("{Name: 1}", new CreateIndexOptions<JobModel>
        {
            Unique = true,
            PartialFilterExpression = /*something here*/
        });
```

But I am not entirely sure what should go in the 'something here' spot. Can I just do a string like `"{ IsArchived: { $eq : false } }"` or is there a better way? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A More typed example:

```
await JobsCollection.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(
                Builders<JobModel>.IndexKeys
                    .Ascending(i => i.Name), 
                new CreateIndexOptions<JobModel>
                {
                    Unique = true,
                    PartialFilterExpression = Builders<JobModel>.Filter.Eq(i => i.IsArchived, true)
                });
```

Comment: The key issue is new CreateIndexOptions() doesn't give you the PartialFilterExpression, but new CreateIndexOptions<type> does.   I completely missed that myself.

Answer (score 0):

Well, It totally did work to just put the quoted thing in there. If anyone has a not-hard coded way, please share it as well.

```
await JobsCollection.Indexes.CreateOneAsync("{Name: 1}", new CreateIndexOptions<JobModel>
{
  Unique = true,
  PartialFilterExpression = "{ IsArchived: { $eq : true } }"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The example provided in the accepted answer is using deprecated methods.

If you´re using a new version of the MongoDB C# driver, the code below is an updated example using driver version 2.18

```
    var indexKeysDefinition = Builders<JobModel>.IndexKeys.Ascending(i => i.Name);
    var createIndexOptions = new CreateIndexOptions<JobModel>
                {
                    Name = "IdxName",
                    PartialFilterExpression = Builders<JobModel>.Filter.Eq(i => i.IsArchived, true)
                };
    
    await JobsCollection.Indexes.
      CreateOneAsync(new CreateIndexModel<JobModel>(indexKeysDefinition, createIndexOptions));
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).